# Creating HTML elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, dynamic

So this is my first task using DOMs so I am still trying to figure a lot of the stuff out but I have to create elements dynamically through javascript, I have managed to make some work but the placement of my elements are usually not in their correct places and I am not really sure how to place them in their designated positions solely on javascript alone. I have to create a textbox and the bear image is suppose to be the profile picture of the user and I need it to have a submit button as well as a cancel button. I am having trouble trying to create an input box with the required buttons using javascript.

I already kinda broke the rules by adding some CSS and elements directly into HTML but it isn't a big deal. For some reason the page has some trouble loading jsfiddle but loads fine as a regular webpage.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqnszer2/1/)

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'inputName';
input.value = 'some value';
input.size = 10;
input.maxLength = 10;
input.className = 'someClass';
var btn = document.getElementByID("goog")[0];
btn.parentElement.insertBefore(input, btn);
```

This isn't generating a button and text box and I'm not really sure why.

[How my current code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYIgd.png)
[How it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9wpp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are using wrong syntax

getElementByID should be **getElementById**

Second issue, get element by id always return one element. If you want to get first element you have to use getElementsByClassName or TagName.

You can define same id 'goog' as a class in all div then it will work

Comment: "*get element by id always return one element…*" or null. ;-)

Comment: @Devil_Doxx hmm i tried to use getElementByClassName and the button with the text box doens't show up

Comment: Yes you are using input text that's why try to use button or submit